# Overriding Viewport metadata property "user-scalable=no" in webview to allow zooming

Tags: android, webview, zooming, viewport

I have a webpage which have a "viewport" tag with the following value:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I want to allow zooming on that page which is displayed in a WebView
so I inject some javascript on onPageFinished() as follow:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes');");
```

but it doesn't work. 
* I also tried rearranging properties like this

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');");
```

or removing the property like this

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0');");
```

with the same result.

- after some trials I found out that I can override maximum-scale only if there was no "user-scalable=no" defined at all in the page.
  for example if the Viewport metadata was like this:

  ```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  ```

everything would work just fine.

- I checked the value of the "viewport" tag after injection using javascript:alert(...), and it was modified by the injection, yet with no actual result.
- I tried setting UseWideViewPort with true or false, and it didn't help neither:

  ```
  webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  //or
  webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  ```

  the samething with setLoadWithOverviewMode()
- zooming doesn't work even programmatically using zoomIn() or zoomOut().
- I've tested using android 2.3 and android 4.4.2 with the same results.
- note: I did read almost all the questions on this site related to zooming and viewport, but nothing was useful in my case.
- my webView settings are defined as follow:

  ```
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
  webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  ```
- So is there any other ways to allow zooming and override the metadata?
- a solution which is compatible with API 10 would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Very nicely asked. This code worked for me, despite being essentially what you stated didn't work, can't say why we are getting different results. You have to change the document's properties since the WebView respects those.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0');");               
}
```